# DEVSimPy vs Simpy

Tags: python-3.x, simpy

I'm currently on the search for differences in simulation software for python. Most hits from a search of google scholar that are comparisons of simulation software only mention DEVSimPy.

So my question is: are DEVSimPy and Simpy the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEVSimPy has nothing to do with SimPy and I do not know why they are using such a similar name.